# Zabbix generate problems by a item

Tags: zabbix

Currently, I have a list that store some data.

this list will upload to Zabbix item by string or (you suggest), and I want to ask can Zabbix read this list and generate problems according the list.

For example, list[1] -> problem 1, list[2] -> problem 2

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might want to create a [custom LLD rule](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#creating_custom_lld_rules). This will require formatting your list in JSON according to the linked manual page. LLD will create items and triggers as per the configuration of prototypes.